# Unity 3D Imported Assets Rotated Backwards in-game

Tags: unity, 3d, assets, import

I'm putting together boilerplate for a Unity FPS game, and having an issue with importing an Asset Store model.

All of my weapons are asset store prefabs. I'm new to Unity, but this makes me think there's something about the imported prefabs themselves that's setting the axis alignment of the models in-game.

Anyone know what I'm missing to fix this and rotate that model in the world (without just writing a model script to rotate it programmatically every time) ?

[image: Weapon Prefabs]

[image: M4 in world]

Comment: You can check if the prefab contains any cs files, but I would bet the artist just aligned them that way. If you have in mind something like Quake, you will have to animate weapons at some point. So there is no harm into writing a simple cs file that continuously rotates weapons. Or do it with the [animation editor](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-keyframed-animation-in-timeline-2019-3#5e1c4378edbc2a00203435bd), by **keyframing** object transformations, if you prefer no script for this. You can solve both, initial rotation and at the same time add a nice Quake like animation.

Comment: More: you can do the animation once and apply to all weapons. And... welcome.